# the second part for a disjunctive question: was it

Tags: grammar

I booked a lesson with a teacher a few days ago, and left a message about my need regarding to English speaking and writing. When I am in the class, the teacher says

> You **wanted** to practice your speaking and writing, **was it**?

I understand she uses past tense because I booked the lesson in the past.

The whole sentence seems to be [a disjunctive question](https://preply.com/en/blog/2020/05/26/types-of-questions-in-english/#scroll-to-heading-3). If it is, the second part should be something like "didn't you", right?

Comment: It is a question tag and not used correctly. You're right! It should be "didn't you?".